# Image in top background of UITableView - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can set an image to my TableView background, but the image is in the center of the view.
How can I set the image to top ?

I'm using staticTableView

```
let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img.jpg"))
self.settingsTableView.backgroundView = image
self.settingsTableView.backgroundView?.frame = CGRectZero
self.settingsTableView.backgroundView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at tableView.backgroundView docs > The background view will be automatically resized to track the size of the table view.  this will be placed as a subview of the table view behind all cells and headers/footers.  default may be non-nil for some devices. ///


You need to use a different approach if you want it there. Probably an imageView behind the table and make the table background color = clearColor()

Comment: ok, but i'm using a static table view (In UItableviewcontroller directly)

Comment: Question, do you want the image behind the cells or on above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a static table and theres no chance of changing it you might want to take an approach like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create the UIImage
    let image = UIImage(named: "testing")

    //Create a container view that will take all of the tableView space and contain the imageView on top
    let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))

    //Create the UIImageView that will be on top of our table
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: image!.size.height))

    //Set the image
    imageView.image = image

    //Clips to bounds so the image doesnt go over the image size
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Scale aspect fill so the image doesn't break the aspect ratio to fill in the header (it will zoom)
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    containerView.addSubview(imageView)

    self.tableView.backgroundView = containerView
}
```

Make the cells or the headers transparent as you wish. I don't know how your UI should work. This method WON'T scroll the imageView but you can simply do it in the scrollView delegate method. Let me know if you need it to scroll and I'll help you out

Comment: The image is now under my TabBar